# JavaScript - How to add bold/strong effect to certain words in a given String

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to highlight certain keywords inside a `string` (these keywords passed as strings in an array). So far I'm able to find where these words start, but I can't obviously surround them with `<b></b>` tags. Any ideas?
JSfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ot6fznoy/).

JS:

```
function getIndicesOf(searchStr, str) {
    var startIndex = 0;
    var index, tmp = [];

    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        tmp.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStr.length;
    }
    console.log(tmp);
}

var vow = "Night gathers, and now my watch begins..";
var bold=["night","watcher"];
for(var i=0;i<bold.length;i++){
    getIndicesOf(bold[i], vow);
}

document.getElementById("vow_p").innerHTML = vow;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use regex capture groups to do what you want:

If you want to include words like : `Night's` and only bold the `Night` part you can use word boundries: `(\b)`

If you want to only include entire words: use `(^|\s)` and `($|\s)`

This maintains the capitalization of the words you are bolding.

```js
var vow = "Night gathers, and now my watch begins. It shall not end until my death. I shall take no wife, hold no lands, father no children. I shall wear no crowns and win no glory. I shall live and die at my post. I am the sword in the darkness. I am the watcher on the walls. I am the shield that guards the realms of men. I pledge my life and honor to the Night's Watch, for this night and all the nights to come.";

var wordsToBold=["night","watcher"];

function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + wordsToBold.join('|') + ')(\\b)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}

document.getElementById("vow_p").innerHTML = makeBold(vow, wordsToBold);
```

```html
<div id="vow_p"></div>
```

Comment: Is that possible we can do partial bold `night` in `nightingale`? I've tried yours but it only works if keyword followed by special character instead of an alphabet?

Answer (score 5):

I would use a regular expression to search for words and surround them with a `<b>` or `<strong>` tag.

```
var s = "Night gathers, and now my watch begins";
s.replace(/(night|watch)/ig, '<b>$1</b>');
// "<b>Night</b> gathers, and now my <b>watch</b> begins"
```

You can also use a `RegExp` object and compile the list of words from an array:

```
var w = ['night', 'watch'];
var r = new RegExp('(' + w.join('|') + ')', 'ig');

var s = "Night gathers, and now my watch begins";
s.replace(r, '<b>$1</b>');
// "<b>Night</b> gathers, and now my <b>watch</b> begins"
```

Comment: Wouldn't these `<b></b>` tags just become part of the `string` and not really apply the bold effect?

Comment: @undroid a raw string cannot have a "bold effect" only displaying it will have any effect. This answer will show the required word(s) in bold *when rendering it*

Comment: @undriod, you are not understanding the output here.  The output from the `replace` is the HTML you would stick inside an element.  It doesn't mean anything to make a string bold unless you're rendering it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I had troubles implementing this on a `textarea` tag but now I understand why.